# Error installing virtualbox on top of ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I have problems installing virtualbox-5.1 on top of my ubuntu 16.04. 
This is the message that I got from 
    dmesg | egrep -i 'error'

```
[    4.083496] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    4.190118] int3403 thermal

: probe of INT3403:02 failed with error -22
[    4.243835] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.243848] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.244796] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.246531] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.246545] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
[ 2976.476894] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=136926 end=136927) time 145 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1072, end
```

Comment: I suggest you to [download Virtualbox package](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) before install it, so you will not suffer any interrupt during the install.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have done that, but the problem persist.

Comment: What kind of problems did you have? Which command did it occurred after?